# Paste Google Maps API v3 link into Email

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Hi I have the following web page which uses the Google Maps API version 3. Is it possible to create a button or right click the map and send the link to someone similar to the Google Maps "Link" button which allows you to "Paste link in email or IM" of the zoom-in level and extent of what you are looking at? I've searched for this but couldn't find anything. Thank you!

https://netfiles.uiuc.edu/alouchio/shared/ztest.shtml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't anything that falls out of the box that will allow you to do this,  but implementing it on your own shouldn't be to difficult.  First off, you will need to define some query string parameters for the page that can be used to navigate to a specific location. To set the correct position and zoom level, you will need three parameters: latitude, longitude and zoom, so your url might look something like:

```
https://netfiles.uiuc.edu/alouchio/shared/ztest.shtml?lat=40.300842&lng=-86.864734&z=6
```

Then, when you initialize your map,  you will need to check for the presence of these parameters, and if so, position the map appropriately:

To Read the Query String, we need a function to handle that part, here is a simple one:

```
// A function to get the qs params, borrowed from http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/09/get-url-parameters-values-with-jquery.html
function getUrlVars()
{
    var vars = [], hash;
    var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
    {
        hash = hashes[i].split('=');
        vars.push(hash[0]);
        vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }
    return vars;
}
```

And then you can check if the correct query string parameters exist, which should be called after you have initialized the map...

```
var params = getUrlVars();   

if (params["lat"] &&  params["lng"] && params["z"])    
{        
    map.setCenter(new GLatLng(parseFloat(params["lat"]), 
        parseFloat(params["lng"]), parseInt(params["z"]));
}
```

Finally,  to produce the link, you can create a button to generate the link information:

```
function showLink()
{   
    var ctr = map.getCenter();
    alert("https://netfiles.uiuc.edu/alouchio/shared/ztest.shtml?lat=" 
+ ctr.lat().toString() + "&lng=" + ctr.lng().toString() + "&z=" + map.getZoom().toString());
}
```

Instead of map.setCenter I used:

```
var myOptions1 = {
  zoom: parseInt(params["z"]),
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(params["lat"]), parseFloat(params["lng"])),
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I will take a look at this and get back to you.

Comment: Hi. Does the main url have to contain the lat/long zoom information when you initially view it? I was hoping I could have a simple web page name such as ...mine/viewer.shtml. And then when I email the link it could add the information to the url ...mine/viewer.shtml?lat=40.300842&lng=-86.864734&z=6 Thanks!

Comment: No,  notice in the solution that I check to see if the parameters exist before trying to navigate the map to the user defined location: if (params["lat"] &&  params["lng"] && params["z"])

Comment: Thank you! I made a couple edits to the syntax most importantly to the map.setCenter code. GLatLng I believe is only for version 2 api, so I edited to this: center: new google.maps.LatLng.

Comment: Sorry about that,  I was working pretty much from memory :)  Glad it worked out for you.